# Choosing only those beers that have at least N number of reviews

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like below. How can I choose only those ids for which there are at least 10 reviews. The data set is quite big and I do not want to select every id, besides few reviews about a beer may not provide a clear insight.

```
beer_beerid    review_profilename     review_overall
  48215            stcules               3.0
  52159            oline73               3.0
  52159       alpinebryant               3.0
  52159            rawthar               4.0
  52159        RangerClegg               3.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do this, Carles has a fine base R solution. With `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(beer_beerid) %>% filter(n() > 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible approach.

You need a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values indicating which rows have an id repeated more than 10 times. Then index you `df` with that.

`table(df$beer_beerid)` will return number of different `beer_beerid`. From that you can take those that are grater that 10.

`which(table(df$beer_beerid) > 10)`. Will return those beerids that are repeated more than 10 times.

Finally you can index you `df`:

```
df[df$beer_beerid == which(table(df$beer_beerid) > 10),
```

Comment: Thanks Guys! While the dplyr command ran fine, using which command threw the error: the longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length. However, I was wondering whether the correct N(9 or 10 or 15 etc.) can be arrived at using visualizisation through ggplot or not!